# Is the placement of set patch-size within my code correct and is set the right command to use?

Tags: netlogo

upon compilation I receive an error message saying set is the wrong commander before patch size 10 what commander should I use instead and why?

```
globals[road?]
to setup
 clear-all
 ask patches [set pcolor green]
   end
 to go
if mouse-down?
[ ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [ edit-world ]

 end



to edit-world

if EDIT_TOOL = "Road" 

 [set pcolor grey
 set patch-size 10
 ]



 end
```

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message you got? Don't paraphrase; copy and paste.

Comment: This isn't something you can use "set" on.

Answer (score 0):

Patch-size can not be changed programatically but only in settings.

All patches have the same size.

What are you trying to do simulation wise with that line? Patch-size should not effect any outcomes.

Edit: I was wrong 
 Set-patch-size changes the size of all patches i.e. scales the view.

Comment: Sorry I want the user to be able to draw out a path in the u.i and the code I have written thus far allows the user to effectively "paint" the path on the screen when EDIT_TOOL= road. However as the user interface window will be large I want to be able to increase the size of the road  that will be painted to contain more patches.

Answer (score 0):

The right command is `set-patch-size`, with the hyphen after `set`.